# Why warnings prevent us from writing optimized programs?

Tags: c++, casting, g++, warnings

Check out this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short GetShort_With_Warning( unsigned long long val ) {
    return *(unsigned short*)&val;
    // mov  ax,word ptr [val] // That's it. Elegance
}

unsigned short GetShort_Without_Warning( unsigned long long val ) {
    unsigned short* shv = (unsigned short*)&val;
    // lea  eax,[val]
    // mov  dword ptr [shv],eax
    return *shv;
    // mov  eax,dword ptr [shv]  
    // mov  ax,word ptr [eax]  
}

int main( void ) {
    printf( "%04x\n", GetShort_With_Warning   ( 0x101234ULL ) );
    printf( "%04x\n", GetShort_Without_Warning( 0x101234ULL ) );
    return 0;
}
```

This is just an example...
There are two functions that do the same, but one gives a warning and the other does not. The assembler code is shown with a comment. Can it be made that the 'elegant' decision does not give a warning?

It's compiled with g++:

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -s -I. -c -o main.o main.cc
```

The following warning appears:

```
main.cc:4:28: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  return *(unsigned short*)&val;
                            ^~~
```

I know what the warning wants to say me.
I know that with today's CPU power this case is not a problem.

Anyway...
My question is why the warnings don't allow me to optimize my code?

Comment: You can always ignore the warning.

Comment: Warnings won't prevent you from anything. But they are good at telling you about things that might be suspect and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which breaking strict aliasing will do).

Comment: Oh and both functions break strict aliasing, but the compiler might not be able to detect it in the second case. And the warning has *nothing* to do with a processors "power".

Comment: Lastly, it's not the optimization flags that causes the warning, but the `-Wall` flag, that tells GCC to enable *most* warnings. I suggest you read [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your version of GCC.

Comment: What about `return static_cast<unsigned short>(val);`?

Comment: @NathanOliver The code in the question and the static cast will do different things depending on endianness.

Comment: [I can't replicate it with `static_cast`](http://rextester.com/WQNBH39402).

Comment: I got same asm with the 3 ways [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/rq6Yz2). (Indeed with different endianness it would be different). (The 2 invalid functions give also correct code).

Comment: I accept NathanOliver answer, because it solves the problem as I want without warning.

Comment: @NathanOliver Won't this do something completely different if the value of `unsigned long long` is greater than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max` due to overflow?

Comment: @fibbles it depends on what the OP wants to do.  If they just want to convert it will work.  If they want a specific set of bits then it might not.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea of "optimizing your code" is based on some beliefs that do not have any foundation in the actual C++ language. You made up a set of rules that you believe should be followed when translating your C++ code into your intended machine code. But in reality none of these rules exist in C++. That's not how C++ works.

In particular, somehow you developed an idea that type-punned pointer access used in your functions above should allow you to access a portion of `unsigned long long` object as an `unsigned short` object. But it doesn't really. There's no such feature in the language and there has never been. Such in-place memory reinterpretation is possible when the target type is a "byte" type. But not when it is `unsigned short`.

Comment: I can agree a bit, but the problem that is solved in the example is real and I want to see how you would decide it ?

Comment: @Ted Cast the `unsigned long long` to a `char` array since that won't break strict aliasing. Figure out how many bytes are in a `char` (probably 1), do the same for `short` (probably 2). In this case cast either the first 2 or last 2 `char`s in the array into `short`s depending on endianness. Then bit shift those `short`s into a single `short` to get your result.

Comment: @Ted: 1) `memcpy` source bytes to the recipient object, 2) type-pun through a union (yes, this is also undefined in C++, but typically has less of a chance to cause problems), 3) reinterpret the source as an array of bytes and "assemble" the desired bytes into the resultant value. See which one of these produces the most efficient code on your platform. If nothing works, then OK, type-pun through pointer reinterpretation but make sure that your compiler does not apply any strict-aliasing optimizations around this code.